# Make RegEx optional groups either BOTH be present and match, or if ONE is missing not match/fail (java)

Tags: java, regex

I have a RegEx pattern I am using and it works (mostly), but there is one bug. I have **3** separate groups to capture the values, **serverXXX** (group 1), **-Site** (group 2, optional) and **YY** (group 3, optional). Below is the RegEx pattern definition:

```
String REGEX_PATTERN =  "server(\\d{1,3})(-[a-zA-Z]*)?(\\d{1,2})?\\.mydomain.com";
```

As you can see by the regex pattern, the **server** is followed by *three* digits, 0-9. The **site** begins with a hyphen (-) and can be any word consisting of any chars a-z (case insensitive), and it is followed by *two* digits, which should be 00 to 99. *Because group 2 and group 3 are optional*, the user does ***not need*** to include the **-SiteYY** portion to a string and it should still pass.

Some tests:

```
server255.mydomain.com // passes, expected
server255-Site69.mydomain.com // passes, expected
server255699.mydomain.com // fails, expected
server25569-Site.mydomain.com // fails, expected
server25569.mydomain.com // passes, BUT SHOULD NOT PASS
```

So basically what is happening, is if the **serverXXX** extends 3 digits for the "XXX" portion, it will *still* pass sometimes since both group2 and group3 are optional because it will read the extra 2 digits as the group 3. However, of course, if more than 5 digits are used, or if 5 digits are used and the "-Site" comes after the "XXX", then it will fail, since its reads it as violating group1's quantifier {1,3} for the "XXX" portion of the string.

*I think I can just combine group 2 and group 3 into a single group*, but I would lose the ability to parse out the **-Site** and **YY** portions. How can I make the regex to ***FAIL*** on this case, `server25569.mydomain.com`, so it doesn't read the extra digits as the third optional group?

Is there any way to Require that if *ANY* of the group2 (-Site) or group3 (YY) are present, that they ***must be present together***??? or would there be an easier fix to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to Require that if ANY of the group2 (-Site) or group3 (YY) are present, that they must be present together??? or would there be an easier fix to this?

You may use this regex:

```sh
server(\d{1,3})(?:(-[a-zA-Z]+)(\d{1,2}))?\.mydomain\.com
```

Take note of optional non-capturing group that contains capture groups #2 and $3.

For Java use:

```
server(\\d{1,3})(?:(-[a-zA-Z]+)(\\d{1,2}))?\\.mydomain\\.com
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BJItcS/1)